# unix command for find a file and replace with new version in all directories

Tags: linux, unix

**Requirement:**
Find a file in all directory and replace it with latest version

Let's say file a.txt is present here

```
    /opt/dir1/a.txt
    /opt/dir1/dir2/a.txt
    /opt/dir2/dir4/a.txt
    /opt/dir3/dir5/a.txt
```

and I have to replace a.txt with newer version.

Can we do it in single command using find and xgarg?

Currently I am doing it manually:

```
    find . -name "a.txt" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

then I am framing cp command manually to it to find result.

```
    cp /tmp/a.txt /opt/dir1/a.txt
    cp /tmp/a.txt /opt/dir1/dir2/a.txt
    cp /tmp/a.txt /opt/dir2/dir4/a.txt
    cp /tmp/a.txt /opt/dir3/dir5/a.txt
```

Is it possible to do it in single line command?

something like this

```
    find  . -name "a.txt" -exec cp /tmp/a.txt {} \;
```

Comment: Did you tried above command find with exec?

Comment: Your command `find  . -name "a.txt" -exec cp /tmp/a.txt {} \;` should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Well! Yes its worked!